# Can I include comments in my PWA manifest file?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'd like to add some descriptive comments to my PWA's `app.webmanifest` file. I know that JSON doesn't typically support comments, but I thought that maybe the file wasn't following strict JSON, (since it isn't saved as `.json`).

[The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) didn't seem to mention anything.